# SQL call to return count by days of month with multi-day items

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm attempting to condense several SQL calls into one, and wanted to know if the following were possible.

Here are are my tables.

```
Organization
    id

Event
    id,
    startDate
    endDate

FavoriteOrgs
    userId
    orgId
```

For each day of the month, I want to return a count of the events occurring on that day.  Not too difficult, until you add the fact that **events can span 2 or 3 days**.

Here's what I have so far, which accurately shows event counts by day, but it only includes the event in count for the day it begins.

```
SELECT DAYOFMONTH( CAST( o.start_date AS DATE ) ) AS dayNum, COUNT( * ) AS count
    FROM favoriteOrgs f, event e, organization o
    WHERE f.user_id =200372
    AND e.profile_id = o.id AND e.profile_id = f.profile_id AND o.id = f.profile_id
    AND e.last_date >=  '$startDate'
    AND e.start_date <=  '$lastDate'
    GROUP BY e.start_date
```

Comment: Can you post your schema

Comment: I posted it in the question, but here it is again: organization(id); event(id, startDate, endDate); favoriteOrgs(userId, orgId)

Comment: Thats not a schema. I don't know what that is. In your mysql client run 'DESC organization', etc. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/describe.html.

Comment: Ah. ID's are ints.  startDate and endDate are timestamps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data model isn't actually modeling all of the entities in your system. One entity is the dates for which you are interested in reporting things.

You should add a table to your database (or use a temporary table, inline table, or whatever else is available with MySQL). The table is simply all of the relevant dates. Even a table that goes back to 1900 and forward to 2100 is going to be fairly small.

The query then becomes trivial:

```
CREATE TABLE Calendar (
    calendar_date DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Calendar PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
)

SELECT
    C.calendar_date,
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
    favoriteOrgs F
INNER JOIN Event E ON
    E.profile_id = F.profile_id AND
    E.last_date >= '$startDate' AND
    E.start_date <= '$lastDate'
INNER JOIN Organization O ON
    O.id = F.profile_id AND
    O.id = E.profile_id
WHERE
    F.user_id = 200372
GROUP BY
    C.calendar_date
```

You also now have an advantage that you can add additional business specific information to calendar dates, like an "is_holiday" column, "economic_quarter" or whatever. Just remember to prefill the table, which is a simple loop that you have to run once.

Comment: Wow. Excellent response, thank you.  Forgive my inexperience here, but currently the 'opportunity' table's 'startDate' and 'endDate' columns are timestamps - as opportunities have start and end times as well as dates.  Is there a way to utilize this solution with timestamps?

Comment: If you only want it broken down by day then I don't think that the code is any different. I'm a MS SQL person though and they have a screwy TIMESTAMP data type, so I'm not sure how MySQL handles it. If you want it broken down by hour or something then you can just `JOIN` in a generated set of numbers from 1 to 24 and bucket based on those along with the dates. The key is thinking of your set of buckets as a dataset itself.